# Как изменить масштаб, не меняя толщину линий?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте. Для масштабирования использую ViewBox (width binding в зависимости от значения Scale).
Теперь появилась необходимость менять масштаб не всех величин. Например, в качестве контента выступил автоматически построенных граф и мне нужно предотвратить масштабирование ширины линий связи, а так же масштабирование границ элементов (или хотя бы запретить уменьшать величину границы меньше единицы), чтобы их было видно на любом масштабе.
Спасибо.

Comment: ViewBox работает только с одним объектом (only one child), а это значит что он трансформирует уже итоговый результат. Выходит что вам нужно будет самому вручную проделать всю работу.

Comment: @cpp_user, жаль, если так. Может, есть иные способы массового изменения масштаба с исключениями?

Comment: Самому перебрать child-ы промасштабировать и исключить то что не нужно.